# Set Background cell color in PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

How to set specific color to active cell when creating XLS document in PHPExcel?

Comment: I get it done with the solution of Muntashir Akon. See below with 33 votes (right now).

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')
        )
    )
);
```

Source: http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2010/07/16/phpexcel-advanced-read-write-excel-made-simple/

Comment: This was incorrect syntax as of 2013-10-17. I have edited to reflect correct syntax.

Comment: How to set background color in Excel Laravel library?

Answer (score 84):

```
function cellColor($cells,$color){
    global $objPHPExcel;

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cells)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array(
             'rgb' => $color
        )
    ));
}

cellColor('B5', 'F28A8C');
cellColor('G5', 'F28A8C');
cellColor('A7:I7', 'F28A8C');
cellColor('A17:I17', 'F28A8C');
cellColor('A30:Z30', 'F28A8C');
```

[image]

Comment: Your functions it's ok, but you are using global, and that's a real error... You should make use of the PHP5 features. Instead, you could try a lambda function such as https://eval.in/39136 :)

Answer (score 38):

This code should work for you:

```
 $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A1')
        ->getFill()
        ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
        ->getStartColor()
        ->setRGB('FF0000')
```

But if you bother using this over and over again, I recommend using `applyFromArray`.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I try applyFromArray, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like there's a bug with `applyFromArray` right now that won't accept color, but this worked for me:

```
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getFill()
    ->getStartColor()
    ->setRGB('FF0000');
```

Comment: Though it is more elegant solution (as I prefer OOP way) it didn't worked for me :/
Used @user198003 provided solution

Answer (score 11):

This always running!

`$sheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('FF0000');`

Comment: In some php version don't can break line at attribute class. Old version.

Comment: **IMPORTANT! Than $objPHPExcel like $sheet is a define from object class PHPExcel. You need use like you instantiated (at new PHPExcel() define).**

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$row.':G'.$row)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('FF0000');

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you do it in `PHPSpreadsheet`, the newest version of `PHPExcel`

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:F1')->applyFromArray([
    'fill' => [
            'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'startColor' => [
                'rgb' => 'FFDBE2F1',
            ]           
    ],
]);
```

alternative approach:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1:F1')
    ->getFill()
    ->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFDBE2F1');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$objPHPExcel
->getActiveSheet()
->getStyle('A1')
->getFill()
->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
->getStartColor()
->setRGB('colorcode'); //i.e,colorcode=D3D3D3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getFill()
    ->getStartColor()
    ->getRGB();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3:B7')->getFill()
->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
```

It's in the documentation, located here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User-Documentation-Overview-and-Quickstart-Guide

Answer (score 0):

You can easily apply colours on cell and rows.

```
$sheet->cell(1, function($row) 
{ 
  $row->setBackground('#CCCCCC'); 
});

$sheet->row(1, ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3']); 
$sheet->row(1, function($row) 
{ 
  $row->setBackground('#CCCCCC'); 
});
```