# PHPExcel: how to set row background (not one cell) [Style_Conditional]

Tags: php, phpexcel, conditional-formatting

```
$cond1 = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional();
$cond1->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CONTAINSTEXT)->
        setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_CONTAINSTEXT)->
        setText('yes');
$cond1->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getEndColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_YELLOW);
```

This code changes the value of the background of the cell to yellow.
How to change the background to all the cells in a row?

Now:

> If the value of the cell is "yes", then change the background of the cells.

Seeking:

> If the value of the cell is "yes", then change the background to all the cells in the row.

Comment: check out the answer on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981676/phpexcel-color-to-specific-row
straight from phpexcel developer

Answer (score 2):

answer from [PHPExcel color to specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981676/phpexcel-color-to-specific-row) straight from its developer.

You cannot style a row in PHPExcel, only a cell or a range of cells

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1:E1')
    ->getFill()
    ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()
    ->setARGB('FF808080');
```

or

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->getStyle('A1:E1')
->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'E05CC2')
        )
    )
);
```

Will set the background fill style for cells A1 to E1