# How to set cell color in phpExcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

**I am using phpexcel library for generate excel file and i want change background color of call**
How to set specific color to active cell when creating XLS document in PHPExcel?
here id my code which i am using

```
  public function exportCSV() {
    // create file name
    $fileName = 'data-'.time().'.xlsx';  
    // load excel library
    $this->load->library('excel');
    // $listInfo = $this->export->exportList();
    $ordersData = $this->admin_development->getDevelopmentDetails();
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // set Header
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Lott Number');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Slot Number');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Party Name');


    // set Row
    $rowCount = 2;
    foreach ($ordersData as $list) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $list->lott_number);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $list->category);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, $list->party_name);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A' . $rowCount)
        ->getFill()
        ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
        ->getStartColor()
        ->setRGB('FF0000');

       
        $rowCount++;
    }
    $filename = "tutsmake". date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").".csv";
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');  
    $objWriter->save('php://output'); 

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773272/set-background-cell-color-in-phpexcel

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA i am tried also this but did not worked

Comment: Have you tried:   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A' . $rowCount)
        ->getFill()
        ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
        ->getStartColor()
        ->setARGB('FF0000');

Comment: Or         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A' . $rowCount)->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')
        )
    )
);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Background cell color in PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773272/set-background-cell-color-in-phpexcel)

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'. $rowCount)->applyFromArray( array( 'fill' => array( 'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000') ) ) );

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$rowCount)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF0000'); 

i am tried both but did not worked...!