# How to set bg color of cell using PHPExcel library in codeigniter3?

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I have implemented PHPExcel library and need to set particluar cell value such as red, green, blue and so on, I try multiple code but not success. Please Help me.

Below is my code but it didn't worked for me.

```
$objPHPExcel->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
                array(
                    'fill' => array(
                        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')
                    )
                )
            );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Background cell color in PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773272/set-background-cell-color-in-phpexcel)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the getActiveSheet()

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
                array(
                    'fill' => array(
                        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')
                    )
                )
            );
```

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
                array(
                    'fill' => array(
                        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')
                    )
                )
            );

I already apply getActiveSheet() before $objPHPExcel but it didn't worked for me. I want to apply cell background color and I am literally tired to apply all the things which are available on internet but it not working for me.

Comment: Strange since it works perfectly in my test code with $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('test.xls');

Answer (score 0):

I already put getActiveSheet() and new code is like .

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
            array(
                'fill' => array(
                    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                    'color' => array('rgb' => '03FC3D')
                )
            )
        );
```

but it didn't worked for me. I want to set cell value into CSV file using PHPExcel library. I tryed multiple solutions via internet but it didn't worked me.

Comment: Do you need to change background color, cell color, cell value?